# three different images and sounds on hover

Tags: javascript, html

I have three images or divs, there is a sound assigned to each image that plays on hover (ambience1 - ambience3). So far it works. But, as of now, the same sound plays, ambience3 to be precise, no matter if I hit image1, image2 or image3. I'm not really familiar with javascript, so I guess it's the js.

Also, I want the sound to stop, not pause, when the cursor leaves the image, and start from the beginning, when the cursor hits the area again. See code below:

```html
<body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
  <div id="image1">
      <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_100649 copy.jpg" />
      <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_100649.jpg" />
      <audio id="audio1">
          <source src="ambience1.mp3"/>
      </audio>
  </div>

  <div id="image2">
      <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_102808 copy.jpg" />
      <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_102808.jpg" />
      <audio id="audio2">
          <source src="ambience2.mp3"/>
      </audio>
  </div>
  
  <div id="image3">
      <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_101713 copy.jpg" />
      <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_101713.jpg" />
      <audio id="audio3">
          <source src="ambience3.mp3"/>
      </audio>
  </div>

  <script>
      var audio = $("#audio1")[0];
      $("#image1").mouseenter(function() {
          audio.play();
          audio.loop = true;
      });
      $("#image1").mouseleave(function() {
          audio.pause();
      });
  </script>

  <script>
      var audio = $("#audio2")[0];
      $("#image2").mouseenter(function() {
          audio.play();
          audio.loop = true;
      });
      $("#image2").mouseleave(function() {
          audio.pause();
      });
  </script>

  <script>
      var audio = $("#audio3")[0];
      $("#image3").mouseenter(function() {
          audio.play();
          audio.loop = true;
      });
      $("#image3").mouseleave(function() {
          audio.pause();
      });
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change `var audio` to three different names in each `<script>` tag (like in below snippet (which not works due to lack of images and sounds). The reason of previous behaviour was that your `audio` variable was global and was override by last script. Use `audio.currentTime = 0;` before pause to play audio from beginning

```html
<body>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
   <div id="image1">
    <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_100649 copy.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_100649.jpg" />
    <audio id="audio1">
    <source src="ambience1.mp3"/>
    </audio>
  </div>

  <div id="image2">
    <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_102808 copy.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_102808.jpg" />
    <audio id="audio2">
    <source src="ambience2.mp3"/>
    </audio>
  </div>
  
  <div id="image3">
    <img class="bottom" src="dcim/20190202_101713 copy.jpg" />
    <img class="top" src="dcim/20190202_101713.jpg" />
    <audio id="audio3">
    <source src="ambience3.mp3"/>
    </audio>
  </div>

  <script>
    var audio1 = $("#audio1")[0];
    $("#image1").mouseenter(function() {
      audio1.play();
      audio1.loop = true;
    });
    $("#image1").mouseleave(function() {
      audio1.currentTime = 0;
      audio1.pause();
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    var audio2 = $("#audio2")[0];
    $("#image2").mouseenter(function() {
      audio2.play();
      audio2.loop = true;
    });
    $("#image2").mouseleave(function() {
      audio2.currentTime = 0;
      audio2.pause();
    });
  </script>

  <script>
    var audio3 = $("#audio3")[0];
    $("#image3").mouseenter(function() {
      audio3.play();
      audio3.loop = true;
    });
    $("#image3").mouseleave(function() {
      audio3.currentTime = 0;
      audio3.pause();
    });
  </script>

</body>
```